# I want to add one more image behind my image and I am doing it with pseudo element before or after but it's not working , or is there any other way?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am trying to add one more picture behind my image and I am trying it with pseudo element before but it's not working.
Is there any other way to add picture behind the image?

```css
.hero-sub-2 img {
  position      : relative;
  width         : 166%;
  height        : 430px;
  border-radius : 20px;
  left          : 43px;
  top           : 50px;
  overflow      : hidden;
  }
.hero-sub-2 img::before {
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  display          : block;
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  background-image : url('/img/360_F_297885365_QNMAlCRXZSHMd0MX5v9QJcP2KhHLLYDc.jpeg');
  top              : 0;
  left             : 0;
  background-size  : cover;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `img` tag doesn't have a `::before` or `::after`. Use a `div` instead. Also, in order to place one behind the other, make sure to use negative `z-index` for the pseudo-element.

```css
.front {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/100);
  position:relative; 
  border: 1px solid red;

}

.front::before {
  position:absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/101);
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="front">
</div>
```